# Invoking a method when another method in different class is invoked in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've got a Xamarin Forms application (actually Mobile Blazor Bindings). There are projects for every platform and one project is shared. MyApp (Shared Project), MyApp.Android etc. I can access to Shared project from every other project but not vice versa.

So I was following a tutorial and for given button in XML in Shared Project

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/subscribeButton"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:text="Subscribe to Notifications" />
```

there is a responding code in Android project (in MainActivity.cs to be precise):

```
var subscribeButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.subscribeButton);
subscribeButton.Click += delegate {
    FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic("news");
    Log.Debug(TAG, "Subscribed to remote notifications");
};
```

So in here, FindViewById finds the button in shared client project and when that button is clicked it just runs what's inside.

My problem is my project there are razor files instead of XML.

What I actually try to accomplish is this:

- In a razor file in Shared Project

```
@code {
    User loggedUser;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    loggedUser = await.getUser();
    if(loggedUser != null)
         subscribeUser(loggedUser.groupName); //user.groupName is a string
}
```

- and In Android Project

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //some code
    if( subsribeUser(string groupname) invoked ) {
        FirebaseMessaging.Instance.SubscribeToTopic(groupname);
    }
}
```

In summary rather than a button click or any other user interaction Client should subscribe to `loggedUser`'s `loggedUser.groupName` topic.

---

- How do I listen if a method is invoked and do some other stuff when it is?
- Is it possible to access a parameters which that method is invoked with?
- Is this handled with Event Handlers?

I got confused because it's not like invoking a method from another class where you have access.

Comment: I don't know enough about Razor to give an answer but I'd suggest breaking your question down into smaller steps. First: can you find the button? Try debugging the project, if there's an error on the line ````subscribeButton.Click += ...````, then your code couldn't find the button.

Comment: My bad when explaining it. I want to achieve it without binding it to a button.This should happen automatically when user is logged in. In the tutorial this happen with button click but I was wondering if I could achieve the same without user interaction. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: "I can access to Shared project from every other project but not vice versa." - this is how references work.  If A references B, A can access B's public elements, but B cannot access A's.